# Create Relationship In Views

Tags: views

I have three content types that have a text field called PID.  How do I tell views there is a relationship between these content types?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to set up a relationship, depending upon how it is to be applied to content.

1. It is not clear how you are suing the PID field, so I will ignore it.  You could create a field with a name like 'relate' and you could enter a term there that identifies a name for a relationship that various content types would share.  You would then set up a **View** to filter for that field with the specific term you want and Views will retrieve all the content that shares that term.  Further filtering could narrow the selection further if you desire.
2. You could use a module such as **Relation** to define a type of relationship and link pairs of content eg. a 'friends' relationship could be used to link two users in a specific type of relationship.

Comment: To complete what Ashlar said above, you then have to add the relevant relationships between the content types in your View, through the the "Add relationship' block in the UI. All CT related to the View's CT will be available there, particularly those with a nodereference or userreference to the original CT.